# Sistema para poner marca de agua en una imagen PHP hace que la imagen sea muy pesada

Tags: php, imagen

tengo un sistema muy simple para poner una marca de agua a una imagen pero el problema es que este hace que una imagen de 300kb llegue a pesar 3-4mb (cosa que me resulta inviable) aclaro que el logo pesa 32kb

El código sería el siguiente

```
# Acá está la imágen a poner marca de agua 300kb
$DirectorioImagen = './../images/carpeta/1/3.jpeg'; 

# Esta es la marca de agua 32kb
$DirectorioMarcaAgua = './../images/marcadeagua.png'; 

# Esta función crea la marca de agua
$MarcaAgua = imagecreatefrompng($DirectorioMarcaAgua); 

# Esta función crea la imágen
$Imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($DirectorioImagen);

$marge_right = 10; # Margen de bordes
$marge_bottom = 10; # Margen de bordes

# Estas funciones obtienen las dimenciones de la marca de agua
$sx = imagesx($MarcaAgua); 
$sy = imagesy($MarcaAgua); 

# Aparentemente esta función copia la imagen 
imagecopy($Imagen, $MarcaAgua, imagesx($Imagen) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($Imagen) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($watermarkImg), imagesy($watermarkImg)); 

# Y esta función guarda la imágen
imagepng($Imagen, $DirectorioImagen); 
imagedestroy($Imagen);
```

No comprendo porque sube tanto el peso de la imágen

Comment: Probé guardando la imágen con la función imagejpeg y el peso se vió reducido perfectamente!

Comment: Date cuenta que jpg no admite transparencia, con lo que si guardas en jpg pierdes ese efecto. Si te vale guardarlo así bien